# Alarm Manager Not Showing Notifications

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am new to android and working on Notification Alarm Manager to show notification. I am on API 23.
The code I posted below is working perfectly but I cannot filgure why it is not notifying me?

Can Any one help me what is the error in it?
Thanks.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button b;
private GoogleApiClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 34);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.PM);

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

**AlarmBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    context.startService(startIntent);
}
}
```

**AlarmService**

```
public class AlarmService extends Service{
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    generarNotificacion();

    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void generarNotificacion(){

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.heart1)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(getResources().getString(R.string.text));

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int mNotificationId = 001;

    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
}

}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<service android:name=".AlarmService"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmBroadcastReceiver"/>
```

Comment: Months are zero-based. If you want November, the corresponding value is `10`. A better option is to use the class constant: `Calendar.NOVEMBER`.

Comment: @MikeM. exactly this solved my problem. Thank You.

Comment: @MikeM. can you help me that how can I set this notification for every half  an hour for one particular day like for 1st December my notification will show up in every half and hour ?

Comment: You'll need to set a regular alarm for the first time you want it to fire on that day. When that fires, setup a repeating alarm for the remainder of the day. However, if you're running on KitKat or above, `setRepeating()` is not exact, so your alarms might not fire exactly when you want, in which case you'll have to use `setExact()`, and set a new alarm for the desired interval each time it fires. If you need specific code examples, you should post a new question. Asking multiple questions in one post is kinda frowned upon.

Comment: ohkay sure..Thanks for the great help.

Comment: @MikeM. Please Add your first comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're trying to set an alarm for today, shortly in the future. However, months are zero-based, so a value of `11` is actually December. If you want November, the corresponding value is `10`. A better option, though, is to use the class constant: `Calendar.NOVEMBER`.